# Unable to get instagram_manage_insights permission for server side application

Tags: facebook, instagram

I have a server side application that read Instagram stories. The documentation here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/stories/ says that instagram_manage_insights is required to query stories. However my app review was rejected by facebook saying that for this permission they need a login. There is no login in a server side application and the documentation doesn't say anywhere that only applications with a front end can query stories. How can I work around that? It doesn't look that any other of the permissions allow me to query stories.

Comment: They have detailed instructions specifically for submitting server-to-server apps, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-review/resources/sample-submissions/server-to-server

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue. In order to get permission (instagram_manage_insights), you actually need a login. Only with the login, FB can authenticate the user and the user can give their permission access to you to that you can use the Graph API to get their story.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).